# Events that should be emitted by a KTable

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am trying to test a topology that, as the last node, has a KTable. My test is using a full-blown Kafka Cluster (through confluent's Docker images) so I am **not** using the `TopologyTestDriver`.

My topology has input of key-value types `String -> Customer` and output of `String -> CustomerMapped`. The serdes, schemas and integration with Schema Registry all work as expected.

I am using Scala, Kafka 2.2.0, Confluent Platform 5.2.1 and `kafka-streams-scala`. My topology, as simplified as possible, looks something like this:

```
val otherBuilder = new StreamsBuilder()

otherBuilder
     .table[String,Customer](source)
     .mapValues(c => CustomerMapped(c.surname, c.age))
     .toStream.to(target)
```

(all implicit serdes, `Produced`, `Consumed`, etc are the default ones and are found correctly)

My test consists in sending a few records (`data`) onto the `source` topic in synchronously and without pause, and reading back from the `target` topic, I compare the results with `expected`:

```
val data: Seq[(String, Customer)] = Vector(
   "key1" -> Customer(0, "Obsolete", "To be overridden", 0),
   "key1" -> Customer(0, "Obsolete2", "To be overridden2", 0),
   "key1" -> Customer(1, "Billy", "The Man", 32),
   "key2" -> Customer(2, "Tommy", "The Guy", 31),
   "key3" -> Customer(3, "Jenny", "The Lady", 40)
)
val expected = Vector(
   "key1" -> CustomerMapped("The Man", 32),
   "key2" -> CustomerMapped("The Guy", 31),
   "key3" -> CustomerMapped("The Lady", 40)
)
```

I build the Kafka Stream application, setting between other settings, the following two:

```
p.put(StreamsConfig.COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, "5000")
val s: Long = 50L * 1024 * 1024
p.put(StreamsConfig.CACHE_MAX_BYTES_BUFFERING_CONFIG, s.toString)
```

So I expect the KTable to use caching, having an interval of 5 seconds between commits and a cache size of 50MB (more than enough for my scenario).

My problem is that the results I read back from the `target` topic always contain multiple entries for `key1`. I would have expected no event to be emitted for the records with `Obsolete` and `Obsolete1. The actual output is:

```
Vector(
    "key1" -> CustomerMapped("To be overridden", 0),
    "key1" -> CustomerMapped("To be overridden2", 0),
    "key1" -> CustomerMapped("The Man", 32),
    "key2" -> CustomerMapped("The Guy", 31),
    "key3" -> CustomerMapped("The Lady", 40)
)
```

One final thing to mention: this test used to work as expected until I updated Kafka from 2.1.0 to 2.2.0. I verified this downgrading my application again.

I am quite confused, can anyone point out whether something changed in the behaviour of KTables in the 2.2.x versions? Or maybe there are now new settings I have to set to control the emission of events?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Kafka 2.2, an optimization was introduced to reduce the resource footprint of Kafka Streams. A `KTable` is not necessarily materialized if it's not required for the computation. This holds for your case, because `mapValues()` can be computed on-the-fly. Because the `KTable` is not materialized, there is no cache and thus each input record produces one output record.

Compare: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6036

If you want to enforce `KTable` materialization, you can pass in `Materilized.as("someStoreName")` into `StreamsBuilder#table()` method.