# How to have a KTable emits only the latest updates?

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

My `KTable` is emitting on each update, instead of the latest updates only.

Please see code below (in Scala):

```scala
object SimpleTable extends App {
  val topic = "simple-table"

  val prodProps = new Properties()
  prodProps.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
  prodProps.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
  prodProps.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
  prodProps.put("acks", "1")
  prodProps.put("retries", "3")

  val producer = new KafkaProducer[String, String](prodProps)

  producer.send(new ProducerRecord[String, String](topic, "key1", "value1"))
  producer.send(new ProducerRecord[String, String](topic, "key2", "value2"))
  producer.send(new ProducerRecord[String, String](topic, "key3", "value3"))
  producer.send(new ProducerRecord[String, String](topic, "key1", "value11"))
  producer.send(new ProducerRecord[String, String](topic, "key2", "value22"))
  producer.send(new ProducerRecord[String, String](topic, "key3", "value33"))

  producer.close()


  val streamProps = new Properties()
  streamProps.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "simple-table-app1")
  streamProps.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092")
  //streamProps.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "group11")
  //streamProps.put(ConsumerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "client11")
  //streamProps.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest")
  //streamProps.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, "18000")
  //streamProps.put(StreamsConfig.COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, "18000")
  //streamProps.put(StreamsConfig.CACHE_MAX_BYTES_BUFFERING_CONFIG, "10485760")
  //streamProps.put(StreamsConfig.NUM_STREAM_THREADS_CONFIG, "1")
  //streamProps.put(ConsumerConfig.METADATA_MAX_AGE_CONFIG, "10000")
  //streamProps.put(StreamsConfig.REPLICATION_FACTOR_CONFIG, 1)
  //streamProps.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_TIMESTAMP_EXTRACTOR_CLASS_CONFIG, classOf[WallclockTimestampExtractor])

  import org.apache.kafka.streams.scala.Serdes._
  implicit val consumeSerdes: Consumed[String, String] = Consumed.`with`[String, String]
  val builder = new StreamsBuilder()

  val simpleTable: KTable[String, String] = builder.table[String, String](topic)
  simpleTable.toStream.print(Printed.toSysOut[String, String].withLabel("simple-table"))


  val streams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), streamProps)
  streams.start()
  Thread.sleep(10000)
  streams.close()
}
```

This App is displaying this:

```
[simple-table]: key1, value1
[simple-table]: key2, value2
[simple-table]: key3, value3
[simple-table]: key1, value11
[simple-table]: key2, value22
[simple-table]: key3, value33
```

I am supposed to have only the latest 3 lines. Please help.

**UPDATE**

As per the solution below, everything works well when I create the KTable like this:

```
val simpleTable: KTable[String, String] =
    builder.table[String, String](topic, Materialized.as[String, String, KeyValueStore[Bytes, Array[Byte]]]("simple-table-store"))
```

Comment: This is the expected behavior for Ktable in Streams. What operation are you planing to perform on Ktable? As I only see to stream print.

Comment: I am actually reading `Kafka Streams In Action`, and just trying to verify the behavior of KTable. According to that book, a KTable is an update stream, it uses a local state store to keep only the latest value for each key. And when pushing messages downstream, only the latest values for each keys are sent. So I was expecting to have only the latest 3 lines, from my App's output. I am wondering while this KTable seems to behave as an Event stream instead of Update stream.

Comment: ok, exactly KTable is a Event Stream. KTable is an abstraction of a changelog stream from a primary-keyed table. Each record in this changelog stream is an update on the primary-keyed table with the record key as the primary key.

Comment: Ok, so... why am I having all the events instead of just the latest updates ? I have played all kind of game with the stream props, specially `commit.interval.ms` and `cache.max.bytes.buffering`, still having all the events. I am using `kafka-streams-scala 2.4.0` and `kafka-client 2.4.0`, it might have an impact. I am completely lost with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer from this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55687101/events-that-should-be-emitted-by-a-ktable?rq=1).

The code used to work with older version of kafka-streams, older than 2.2.

**CopyPasted**

> In Kafka 2.2, an optimization was introduced to reduce the resource footprint of Kafka Streams. A KTable is not necessarily materialized if it's not required for the computation. This holds for your case, because mapValues() can be computed on-the-fly. Because the KTable is not materialized, there is no cache and thus each input record produces one output record.
>
> Compare: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6036
>
> If you want to enforce KTable materialization, you can pass in Materilized.as("someStoreName") into StreamsBuilder#table() method.